# Set default nodeJs version Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs

I am working with an older angular project that will not run with the latest nodeJs version. So when I do other projects I have to set my current nodeJs version to the latest one and when I run my angular project I have to set it to a older one. I would like to have some configuration in the angular project that automatically sets the nodeJs version to a specific version when you do ng serve and run the project.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the required node version to the `package.json` file like this

```
 "engines" : { 
   "npm" : ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0",
   "node" : ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0"
 }
```

Comment: Nice, what is referred to as engines? and how should I take the < vs > if the angular project is run I want to use nodeJs version v14.18.1. How would I specify this using this example?

Comment: you can add like 
 "engines" : { 
   "npm" : "8.0.0",
   "node" : "14.18.1"
 }